# Run JavaScript, jQuery, Ajax on PhoneGap Android App?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, phonegap

Is it possible to use JavaScript, jQuery and Ajax on a PhoneGap App for Android? And if so, how can this be possible? Because, when I run my index.html on Mamp, it works. But when I run it on my local machine, it does not work.

So my question is - will my project run on a PhoneGap App for Android?
And if so, how does this work? Does PhoneGap Apps have some kind of a integrated Mamp (or something like that), that emulates a webserver?
I have tried to google it, but can not find a answer.

I'm sorry, but I don't have a Wifi at home right now, so I got to wait some weeks before I can deploy my test on Android over PhoneGap.
I just would like to know right now, if it works or not - and when it works, how it can work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Phonegap does not have integrated MAMP, it is not a web server. Think of it as more of a web browser -- PhoneGap only runs web assets like HTML, JS, CSS. You would then make your ajax calls to your MAMP server from your PhoneGap app to deliver data.

Just give it a try, PhoneGap has low barrier to entry and this will be the best way to see how it works.

[Getting Started with PhoneGap.](http://docs.phonegap.com/getting-started/)